# Calculate average time a issue took in a state

Tags: jira

I have the follow JQL that give me the issues from last 3 sprints and have "Story Points".

```
Sprint in (13856, 13855, 13854) and "Story Points[Number]" is not EMPTY
```

I would like to group by "Story Points[Number]" and calculate the average time where a Issue got into "IN DEV" status for the last time and to "READY FOR QA" also for the last time. This would give me the average time a issue took in "IN DEV" status for each "Story Points[Number]".

Is it possible?

What I've tried so far:

- Exporting the issues, but it does not export the issue history.
- Use a python library to request history for all issues and calculate by myself. As my company uses oAuth, I couldn't figure out how to authenticate.

Comment: https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Marketplace-Apps-Integrations/Jira-reports-for-Average-time-spent-in-status/ba-p/1882838

Comment: https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1221462/time-between-statuses?hosting=cloud&tab=overview